# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5 daterangepicker android

Tags: java, android, datepicker, date-range

I am using dateRangePicker but I am facing the below error when I click.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.dev:layout/mtrl_picker_dialog: Binary XML file line #17 in com.dev:layout/mtrl_picker_header_title_text: Error inflating class TextView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.dev:layout/mtrl_picker_header_title_text: Error inflating class TextView
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0400bd a=6}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:596)
        at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:3961)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1064)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:968)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:100)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:95)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:115)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:242)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1061)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1233)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1119)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1231)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1119)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialDatePicker.onCreateView(MaterialDatePicker.java:209)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.performCreateView(DialogFragment.java:489)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

onclick:

```
 MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();

                CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
                builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build());

                MaterialDatePicker<?> picker = builder.build();

                picker.show(getFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

added in AppTheme:

```
 <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">#FFFFFF</item>
```